# How to have ModelState use the TempData mechanism?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, session

As far as I can tell, there's a bit of a problem with ASP.NET's ModelState mechanism.  It only stays around for the context of the current HTTP request.  So let's say I just want to use server-side validation.  I can write this in my `.cshtml` view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "MyController", routeValues: new { Area = "MyArea" }, method: FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @autocomplete = "off" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeTextbox, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SomeTextbox)
    ...
```

... where my model is:

```
public class SomeModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Some Textbox")]
    [Required]
    public string SomeTextbox { get; set; }
```

If I now check for model state validity in my action method, the validation message ("The Basic Textbox field is required.") is correctly displayed by the `ValidationMessageFor` helper when I submit the form with no content in the textbox:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new SomeModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SomeModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Server-side model validation failed; abort!
            return View(model);
        }
        ...
```

However, this stops working if, instead of POSTing to `/Index`, I POST to something like `/Update` and then do a redirect back to `/Index` if there's an error in the model.  This is because ModelState only lasts for the current HTTP request context, and `ValidationMessageFor` relies on ModelState to get its error messages.  When you redirect back to `/Index`, this state is lost.

This is exactly what `TempData` was designed to get around, as it keeps its session state until it is read in a later HTTP request.  However, ModelState doesn't seem to use a mechanism like this.

Is there a way to have ModelState use some mechanism like `TempData` so that if I POST to a different URL and redirect back upon an invalid model state, I correctly get the error messages rendered to the page using `ValidationMessageFor` (and, more generally, I retain the ModelState from the form submission before I redirected)?

Comment: That's not the problem - the `[Required]` is working.  It's just that the ModelState is being lost on the redirect, so the error isn't displayed.

Comment: My bad, I commented too fast. Can you show us the code you use in `Update` to redirect to `Index`?

Comment: No, but you can add the `ModelStateDictionary` to `TempData` (although its not clear from your question what you want to do or why)

Comment: How do you set it at the other end?  `Controller.ModelState` only has a `get` method.  Or do you just not bother setting it on the controller when checking it?

Comment: You don't set it on the other controller

Answer (score 1):

OK so basically I've found out that what I was describing was the PRG model, which isn't usually used in ASP.NET.  You usually POST back to the same URL and so you have the HTTP context in which you POSTed, and only redirect in the case of a success in which case you no longer need the ModelState.  People have come up with workarounds to implement PRG in ASP.NET, though, such as:
https://andrewlock.net/post-redirect-get-using-tempdata-in-asp-net-core/